# How to locally execute a ruby script hosted on github in single CLI command

Tags: ruby, shell, github, file-io, wget

Want to execute [this script](https://gist.github.com/JackDrogon/53678a54a326b9aaf4102180eeb58cab) 
on my laptop which has ruby already installed
so I first download the script office-thinner.rb and then run
sudo ruby office-thinner.rb

How can I avoid the 1st step of downloading of the file every time and in single command get the script and execute it?

Can wget, filestream and linux piping do the magic?

Comment: Checkout https://serverfault.com/questions/226386/wget-a-script-and-run-it

Comment: You may directly achieve it through `wget -O - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JackDrogon/53678a54a326b9aaf4102180eeb58cab/raw/91cf80f71b1358355db87fb6036e7f10e49d83a6/office-thinner.rb | bash`

Answer (score 2):

Either you go the full "bash run" and pipe the script into bash (or the shell of your choice), which will then also take into account all the stuff that happens when your shell executes (e.g. if you are using `[rvm][1]` it will make `ruby` being your selected ruby):

```
wget -O - https://gist.github.com/JackDrogon/53678a54a326b9aaf4102180eeb58cab | bash
```

Or, you give the script to the ruby interpreter yourself:

```
wget -O - https://gist.github.com/JackDrogon/53678a54a326b9aaf4102180eeb58cab | ruby
```

or

```
wget -O - https://gist.github.com/JackDrogon/53678a54a326b9aaf4102180eeb58cab | /usr/bin/ruby2.5 --verbose
```

In the later case you can also use options to ruby (e.g. switch on the JIT compiler, verbosity settings, etc.

In the first case, your shell will most likely only execute the script if it has the magical shebang at top (e.g. `#/usr/bin/env ruby`). In the second case, ruby will take whatever comes.

Comment: The problem when i tried your solution is that my command requires sudo privileges and with that the prompt for password does not halt the shell and throws out an error.  

    ```[1]  + 370 done                    wget -O -  |
           371 suspended (tty output)  sudo ruby
    
    ~
    ✦2 ➜ fg
    [1]  + 370 done       wget -O -  |
           371 continued  sudo ruby
    zsh: can't set tty pgrp: operation not permitted.```
    
Any idea how to force the halt at password prompt?

Comment: @JagdishAdusumalli Simplest solution is to run the first shell as sudo already (`sudo -i`).